# How to install Lexmark S308 printer?

Tags: printing

I have a multi function lexmark printer with a instalation cd but can get the .exe to run, Im new to the ubuntu world so i dont know how to install third party software yet. Thank for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Printer shouldn't need driver. The one on the disk will be for windows anyway so that probably won't help. Just hook it up and go to Printing (search it up in the Dash, should be under Settings). Hit the big plus, and your printer should show up on the list of devices on the window then brought up.

Comment: thanks a lot but when i choose the printer it ask me for the driver which i cant find on the database list. other options are to provide the "ppd" or search for driver online but the last one wont help me so how do i find my printers ppd.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below. It explains how to install your printer in Ubuntu:

http://www.dylanmtaylor.com/2011/04/17/fixing-lexmark-printer-driver-installation-in-ubuntu-11-04/